# x2go scaling issue from a Windows client

Tags: windows-10, client, scaling, xfce, x2go

I am using x2go to connect to a remote Ubuntu Server 18.04 with XFCE installed from my local pc with a local resolution of 3840 x 2160 on a 17.3" screen.

However, when I connect from my Windows 10 to the remote desktop, there appears to be a scaling issue (everything is too small).

Following is a screenshot of what I see with the x2go client:
[image: x2go client scaling issue screenshot]

Could I get some help on how to solve this? If additional information is needed, please let me know.

Comment: I’ve got a similar problem when connecting from Ubuntu to Ubuntu, so it does not seem to be related to Windows. However, X2Go is not a programming tool, so this question does not belong on Stack Overflow, it would better fit to [su].

Comment: [This solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1256722/250300) helped me but it is not portable to Windows, unfortunately…